# HTML form not taking inputs

Tags: html

The form is displayed on the browser, but when I roll my cursor over the text fields, it just doesn't take the input. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Chemicals.ltd</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        </head>
    <body>
      <!--> <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\chem.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div><!-->
        <h2> Welcome to TOXIC TRADERS ! </h2>
        <p>We trade chemicals , for industrial or lab use.<br> Please enter Relevant info in the form </p>

        <form name="Details" action="/ChemControl" method="POST">
        Chemical Name: <input type="text" name="Chemical"><br>
        Hazard Level(No.): <input type="text" name="Hazard type"><br>
        Lab/Company Name: <input type="text" name="Lab Name" ><br>
        Serial No.: <input type="text" name="Serial No."><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Info">
        </form>      

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _when i roll my cursor over the text fields , it just doesn't take the input_?

Comment: unless you click on the submit button,values can not be passed just by rolling over cursor

Comment: like , when i move my cursor to the text field , i should get a blinking line,which i don't .... and when i move my cursor to submit, it doesn't turn blue or get pressed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overlaying your form with a div, that blocks the input. Remove it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chemicals.ltd</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
<body>
    <h2> Welcome to TOXIC TRADERS ! </h2>
    <p>We trade chemicals , for industrial or lab use.<br> Please enter Relevant info in the form </p>

    <form name="Details" action="/ChemControl" method="POST">
    Chemical Name: <input type="text" name="Chemical"><br>
    Hazard Level(No.): <input type="text" name="Hazard type"><br>
    Lab/Company Name: <input type="text" name="Lab Name" ><br>
    Serial No.: <input type="text" name="Serial No."><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Info">
    </form>      

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you ! but what if i want to set a picture in the background, which fits to screen, and then do form operation over it ?

Comment: Try lowering the z-index, maybe to -999, or better use some css3, e.g.: body {
  background-image: url(imagename.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Your html comments are invalid

should be

`<!--   <html not displayed>  -->`

Not

`<!-->   <html not displayed>  <!-->`

Result is the html that it appears you are trying to comment out is masking the form

Answer (score 0):

Your div tag with 100% height and 100% width has covered the entire view port like a modal form, hence the area beneath it has become non-clickable. Remove the height and width from  tag like below:

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;'>
  <img src='C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\chem.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font size is probably set to zero.

Add this to your css style file:

```
input {
   font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Or add the style directly on the HTML tag:

```
<input style="font-size: 10pt;" type="submit" value="Send Info">
```